# "'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" when trying to do commands

Tags: mysql

The other day I was using MySQL on my local database fine from the terminal. However, when I rebooted the next day and tried to use it, I get the following error for just about EVERYTHING related to MySQL.

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I have been going at this for a couple hours now.

Comment: "using password: NO"... I suggest you find out the password or a method to reset it ;)

Comment: I'm new to linux. How exactly do I "login"? Not only that, but I think while trying to battle this issue, I had "using password: YES" as well.

Comment: from command line `mysql -u root -p` and then supply the password you set during installation :) and here is a method to reset: http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password

Comment: matt@Matt-Desktop:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You are using root all the time but are you sure it is not another username?

Comment: I just tried the only other name I know. I guess I'm not sure?

Comment: Solved. Will answer when possible.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to reset mysql root password:

Change /etc/mysql/my.cnf configuration file and add `skip-grant-tables`:

```
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
```

Restart service, and login with root without password, then change the root password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

Remove `skip-grant-tables` entry from my.cnf and restart mysql.

Comment: Looked promising until I got "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement". This statement = setting password for root.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, sudo mysql_secure_installation, if you can't just set a new password with sudo mysqladmin -u root -p  password.
Alternatively:
3 - Delete current root@localhost account

mysql> DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

4 - Recreate your user

mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

5 - Give permissions to your user (don't forget to flush privileges)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

As you are new to Linux. Try reading these articles ([this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this one](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04) too) related to MySQL installation. This will help you understand meaning and reason behind each command which you are using.

Comment: While providing links as references is great, telling the OP what he is missing is even better. Maybe copy the key information from the links into your answer. If the links go dead at some point, another user looking at your answer will have nowhere to turn.

Comment: @Zzzach... Thanks for the suggestion :) I was in a bit of hurry as I had my semester end exams . Will update the answer ASAP.